# Using Sets in Classes; Adding and Removing elements from sets

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay, so I have been given two driver files and I have to create a class so the driver files will work.. Here are the instructions:

> Your set class must be named `Set`. Each object of the set class should contain a list of all of the elements of the class (instance data).  This list should be named `members` (inside the class, you must use a python list named `self.members` – do NOT use the Python `Set` class, make your own).  For this assignment, you must include the following methods:
>
> - `__init__()`  The constructor will be a default constructor that does not take any arguments.  It will initialize the list (instance data) with an empty list.
> - `add_element(integer)`  This method will add one integer to the set.  You may assume that only one integer is passed to it.  There is no need to validate that the argument is an integer for this assignment.
> - `remove_element(integer)`  This method will remove the value passed to it from the set.
> - `remove_all()`  This method removes all values from the list, so that it is empty.
> - `has_element(x)`  This method takes an integer and returns `True` if it is a member of the calling object.  Otherwise it returns `False`.
> - `__repr__()`  This method allows the `Set` to be printed using python’s `print()` function by returning a string.  The set should be printed using regular set notation: {element1, element2, … element} when there are n elements.  `{}` should be printed if the set is empty
> - `__str__()`  This method allows the Set to be used with python’s `str()` function.  It returns a string that is identical to the string returned by the `__repr__()` method.
> - `__add__`  This method overloads the `+` operator to provide the union functionality for our Set class.  This method returns a new `Set` that contains all of the members of both Sets being added.
> - `intersect(x)`  This method returns a `Set` object that contains the elements that are present in the calling `Set` and `Set` `x` (the one being passed).
> - `has_subset(x)`  This method is similar, but not identical to `is_element()` from last week.  Instead of being passed an integer, the parameter should be another `Set`.  It returns `True` if the `Set` being passed is a subset of the calling `Set`.  Otherwise it returns `False`.
>
> Part 1:
>
> Write the class with a default constructor (no arguments will be passed), `addElement`, `removeElement`, and `removeAll` functions.

I am so confused as to how I am supposed to set this up! If I can get help with this first part, I think I can do the other three parts. Here's what I have so far... but I know it's completely screwed up! The "set" thing is really screwing me up. I don't know how to add or remove anything for this.

```
class Set:
     def __init__(self):
          self.members = []
          set = {}        
     def add_element(self):
            return self.add()        
     def remove_element(self):
          return self.remove()        
     def get_remove_all(self):
          self.remove_all()
```

Comment: I'm so confused as to why you would use a Python list instead of a dict for storing the members.

Comment: @AliAfshar - it's an assignment that specifically requires a list.

Comment: @tdelaney it is a terrible assignment for lists, because it teaches you something very bad, and fails to teach you something very important about data structures. You should tell your teacher this, and please pass on my details if your teacher wants to chat about it.

Comment: @AliAfshar - I disagree. All of these list actions are useful and generally applicable. The OP learns a bit about classes and gains some insight into sets. Which data structures are best used where is another topic that the teacher likely talks about as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give you a complete solution to your problem, since this is an assignment that I suppose should be solved by yourself...

The assignment asks you to create a class, not functions. So here is how you could start:

```
class Set(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []

    def add_element(self, some_integer):
        if not some_integer in self.members:
            self.members.append(some_integer)

    def get_remove_all(self):
        self.members = []
...
```

Comment: the OP has created a class

Comment: this doesn't work... you should only append the integer if its not already in the list.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, right. This was more about the class-method skeleton as a starting point. But I can add one working solution for `add_element`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, he/she has: After I added my answer the OP was edited accordingly. At the point when I wrote this, it was a collection of functions without a class...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I see, maybe it was not formatted properly and I just overlooked it. My bad.

Comment: no worries, the edit you made  `if not some_integer in self.members:` will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

**I intentionally implemented the wrong solution**, but you should offer this to your teacher as a much better way of doing this ridiculous assignment. I mean come on, your teacher can't even be consistent about the naming of the methods.

```
class Set(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.members = {}

    def addElement(self, member):
        self.members[member] = None

    def removeElement(self, member):
        if member in self.members:
            del self.members[member]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Item not in the set.')

    def removeAll(self):
        self.members = {}
```

Comment: But that doesn't really help you learn to how to manipulate lists.

Comment: Point is: this is a very bad example of when to use lists. And of course I won't do your homework for you. I hope this illustrates a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this assignment is to apply list operations to a problem. It doesn't matter the that Set class is kinda silly... its about getting practice with lists. Some of the things you can do with a list are `x in mylist`, `del mylist[x]`, `mylist.append(x)` and `[x for x in mylist if x in otherlist]`. So, just start applying them for the Set class:

```
class Set(object):   # python 2.x, in 3.x you can just say class Set:

    def __init__(self):
        self.member = []

    def add_element(self, integer):
        if integer not in self.member:
            self.member.append(integer)

    ...
```